# global variable in Node.js: weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below couple of files of javascript:

```
const { testFunc2 } = require("./TestFunction");


function home(val){
    global.context={};

    global.context.val = val;
}

home(3);
testFunc2();
//homeFunction.js
```

Below is `TestFunction.js`:

```
exports.testFunc2=()=>{
    console.log(context.val);
}
```

This code prints 3 as the output, even though I have not put `global` before `context` in testFunc2. How does this actually works? My guess is that node looks for a variable named context in local scope, if it is not able to find it local, it moves onto global scope. Is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes, the explicit `global` object is a feature peculiar to Node JS

It is an object that is *shared* between all the modules in a Node JS program, even when you don't feel like you are actively doing anything to cause the sharing (as you say).

If there is no local variable called `context`, your reference to `context` falls through to the global `context`, which you wrote into using `global.context=`.

In a way, it is similar to what would happen in a browser if you wrote to `window.xyz` and then imported a module that tried to read `xyz`.